# trouble constructiing url encoded link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

if i do this:

```
  <a target="_blank" href="<%=Url.Encode(sitelink)%>"> LINK TO SITE</a>
```

I get the link encoded but prepended with the current local domain "http://localhost/http://...."

whats the proper way to do this

Answer (score 1):

The `Url.Encode` method is used to escape special characters for usage in the query part of a url - it's not meant to be applied to the entire url, because that will escape things like the `://` at the beginning (which is why you get the local domain prepended, because it's no longer a full URL, instead getting interpreted as a relative url).